# How to keep BaseView's two-way bindable Properties and event when using CustomRenderer : ViewRenderer<A, B>

Tags: xamarin.forms

First I wanna use this custom UITextField named JVFloatLabeledEntry in X.F. Here is the reference to this custom UITextField https://github.com/gshackles/JVFloatSharp

So here are my steps:

**XF side:**
1. JVFloatLabeledEntry.cs

```
public class JVFloatLabeledEntry : Entry
    {
        public Color FloatingLabelColor { get; private set;}
        public Color FloatingLabelActiveColor { get; private set;}

        public JVFloatLabeledEntry () : base()
        {
            WidthRequest = 300;
            HeightRequest = 44;
            FloatingLabelColor = Color.Gray;
            FloatingLabelActiveColor = Color.Black;
        }           
    }
```

**iOS side:**
2.  JVFloatLabeledTextField.cs this is the custom UITextField I wanna use. You can find this file in the github https://github.com/gshackles/JVFloatSharp
3. JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer.cs this is my CustomRenderer which creates a brand new JVFloatLabeledTextField and sets it to the NativeControl

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (JVFloatLabeledEntry), typeof (JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer))]
namespace DutyFreeCollection.iOS
{
    public class JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer<JVFloatLabeledEntry, JVFloatLabeledTextField>
    {
        public JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer () {}

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<JVFloatLabeledEntry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            var jfflEntry = e.NewElement;
            if (jfflEntry != null) {
                const float JVFieldHMargin = 10.0f;
                const float JVFieldFontSize = 16.0f;
                const float JVFieldFloatingLabelFontSize = 11.0f;
                // Now whenever I use JVFloatLabeledEntry on XF side, this newView is instead used
                var newView = new JVFloatLabeledTextField (
                    new RectangleF(JVFieldHMargin, 0, (float)jfflEntry.WidthRequest, (float)jfflEntry.HeightRequest))
                {
                    Text = jfflEntry.Text,
                    Placeholder = jfflEntry.Placeholder,
                    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (JVFieldFontSize),
                    ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing,
                    FloatingLabelFont = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (JVFieldFloatingLabelFontSize),
                    FloatingLabelTextColor = jfflEntry.FloatingLabelColor.ToUIColor(),
                    FloatingLabelActiveTextColor = jfflEntry.FloatingLabelActiveColor.ToUIColor(),
                    BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
                };

                SetNativeControl (newView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is after set the new JVFloatLabeledTextField to native control, all members like event TextChanged and properties like TextProperty of Entry on XF side are gone. i.e.

```
JVFloatLabeledEntry floatLabeledEntry = new JVFloatLabeledEntry();
floatLabeledEntry.TextChanged += (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
// Never comes here, event TextChanged of JVFloatLabeledEntry is gone, but why? Since JVFloatLabeledEntry derived from Entry, why is the event TextChanged gone?
};
```

Same thing happens for all the other members of this custom Entry, like

`floatLabeledEntry.SetBinding(JVFloatLabeledEntry.TextProperty, "ANY_BINDING_FIELD"); // The two-way binding is gone as well.`

I really reached bottle neck, could anyone please tell me how to keep JVFloatLabeledEntry(CustomEntry)'s base class Entry's properties binding and EventHandlers. Thank you very much.

Comment: you need a bit more context - what code you have, what the side effects are and where do they happen - I can't understand your question at all

Comment: @StenPetrov, I really appreciate your advice. Now I think the question is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly the problem is in the way you initialize the iOS native control - there are no events you're listening to on the native side (including lack of bindings), you're initializing the native control in a fire-and-forget manner.

You need to add a code to translate the native events into forms events. I'm not familiar enough with the custom control you're using, but in the renderer after you init the control you'd need to hook to its events, something along the lines:

```
newView.TextChangedEvent+=(s,e) => jfflEntry.OnTextChanged(jffl, new TextChangedEventArgs(e.NewText);
```

the code above is made up but it should give you a good idea what to do, if not - just ask what's unclear

Comment: yeah that's exactly my problem. But could you please give me one real sample about how to hook up TextChangedEvents from iOS UITextField to XF Entry? I tried this newView.TextChangedEvent += (object sender1, EventArgs event1) => jfflEntry.OnTextChanged(jfflEntry, new TextChangedEventArgs(e.OldElement.Text, e.NewElement.Text)); But I got cannot assign to 'TextChangedEvent' because it is a method group. I'm new to iOS developing as you can tell. :D

Comment: I just looked at the JF...Entry code and it inherits EntryElement from Monotouch.Dialog, try hooking up to its Changed event

Comment: could you give a real example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (JVFloatLabeledEntry), typeof (JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer))]
namespace DutyFreeCollection.iOS
{
    public class JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer<JVFloatLabeledEntry, JVFloatLabeledTextField>
    {
        private UIColor defaultTextColor;

        public JVFloatLabeledEntryRenderer () {}

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<JVFloatLabeledEntry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            var jfflEntry = e.NewElement;
            if (jfflEntry != null) {
                const float JVFieldHMargin = 10.0f;
                const float JVFieldFontSize = 16.0f;
                const float JVFieldFloatingLabelFontSize = 11.0f;

                var newView = new JVFloatLabeledTextField (
                    new RectangleF(JVFieldHMargin, 0, (float)jfflEntry.WidthRequest, (float)jfflEntry.HeightRequest))
                {
                    Text = jfflEntry.Text,
                    Placeholder = jfflEntry.Placeholder,
                    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (JVFieldFontSize),
                    ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing,
                    FloatingLabelFont = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (JVFieldFloatingLabelFontSize),
                    FloatingLabelTextColor = jfflEntry.FloatingLabelColor.ToUIColor(),
                    FloatingLabelActiveTextColor = jfflEntry.FloatingLabelActiveColor.ToUIColor(),
                    BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
                };                      

                SetNativeControl (newView);


                this.UpdatePlaceholder ();
                this.UpdatePassword ();
                this.UpdateText ();
                this.UpdateColor ();
                this.UpdateKeyboard ();

                newView.EditingChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs a) {
                    jfflEntry.Text = newView.Text;
                };
                newView.ShouldReturn = new UITextFieldCondition (this.OnShouldReturn);
//              newView.EditingDidBegin += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args) {
//                  jfflEntry.IsFocused = true;
//              };
//              newView.EditingDidEnd += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args) {
//                  jfflEntry.IsFocused = false;
//              };
                this.defaultTextColor = newView.TextColor;
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IVisualElementRenderer> (this, "Xamarin.ResignFirstResponder", delegate (IVisualElementRenderer sender) {
                    if (newView.IsFirstResponder) {
                        newView.ResignFirstResponder ();
                    }
                }, null);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Entry arg_06_0 = base.Element;
            if (e.PropertyName == Entry.PlaceholderProperty.PropertyName) {
                this.UpdatePlaceholder ();
            }
            else {
                if (e.PropertyName == Entry.IsPasswordProperty.PropertyName) {
                    this.UpdatePassword ();
                }
                else {
                    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName) {
                        this.UpdateText ();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextColorProperty.PropertyName) {
                            this.UpdateColor ();
                        }
                        else {
                            if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.InputView.KeyboardProperty.PropertyName) {
                                this.UpdateKeyboard ();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);
        }

        private bool OnShouldReturn (UITextField view)
        {
            base.Control.ResignFirstResponder ();
//          base.Element.SendCompleted ();
            return true;
        }

        private void UpdateColor ()
        {
            if (base.Element.TextColor == Color.Default) {
                base.Control.TextColor = this.defaultTextColor;
                return;
            }
            base.Control.TextColor = base.Element.TextColor.ToUIColor ();
        }

        private void UpdateKeyboard ()
        {
            base.Control.ApplyKeyboard (base.Element.Keyboard);
        }

        private void UpdatePassword ()
        {
            if (base.Element.IsPassword && base.Control.IsFirstResponder) {
                base.Control.Enabled = false;
                base.Control.SecureTextEntry = true;
                base.Control.Enabled = base.Element.IsEnabled;
                base.Control.BecomeFirstResponder ();
                return;
            }
            base.Control.SecureTextEntry = base.Element.IsPassword;
        }

        private void UpdatePlaceholder ()
        {
            base.Control.Placeholder = base.Element.Placeholder;
        }

        private void UpdateText ()
        {
            if (base.Control.Text != base.Element.Text) {
                base.Control.Text = base.Element.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't set jfflEntry.IsFocused, cause IsFocused is internal property in VisualElement, anyone knows how to access or set IsFocused property of Entry?
Same for base.Element.SendCompleted();